# Nativescript-vue + Meteorjs Backend

Tags: meteor, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

I am learning nativescript-vue and now i want to use nativescript-vue with meteorjs backend. Can anyone tell me how to integrate nativescript-vue with meteorjs backend?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter which backend you use. End of the day you are going to communicate with your server using RESTful services. You may use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [Http](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http) module to hit the services from your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to any API with Nativescript. If your backend have only simple GET and POST method, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@billow/nsv-http) plugins will help a lot with Nativescript-Vue